# C# Pattern to cache actions accepting generic parameters

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-3.5

I want to create a list of actions to perform on a drawing object. Here's what the non-generic code would look like:

```
private Dictionary<String, Action<Drawing, String>> actions = new Dictionary<String,  Action<Drawing, String>>();
private void LoadActions()
{
     actions.Add("Height", (d, s) => d.Height = Double.Parse(s));
     actions.Add("Width", (d, s) => d.Width = Double.Parse(s));
}
private void ProcessDrawing(Drawing drawing, String prop, String value)
{
     actions[prop](drawing, value);
}
```

The problem I have is that the Drawing class is a generic one (`Drawing<T>`) so I can't define actions like the following because T is not defined:

```
Dictionary<String, Action<Drawing<T>, String>> actions = new Dictionary<String,  Action<Drawing<T>, String>>();
```

Without caching the code looks like this:

```
private void ProcessDrawing<T>(Drawing<T> drawing, String prop, String value)
{
     var actions = new Dictionary<String, Action<Drawing<T>, String>>();
     actions.Add("Height", (d, s) => d.Height = Double.Parse(s));
     actions.Add("Width", (d, s) => d.Width = Double.Parse(s));
     actions[prop](drawing, value);
}
```

So how can I cache a bunch of actions accepting a generic type of parameter?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class of all Actions is `MulticastDelegate`. You would have to define your dict as `Dictionary<String,MulticastDelegate>` and use appropriate castings after retrieving your actions from the dict.

**EDIT**:
Tests show that lambda expressions can obviously not be directly assigned to variables of type `MulticastDelegate`. This is because the type of the lambda expression parameters is inferred from the type of the variable (or method parameter) it is assigned to. Therefore assign it first to a variable with the right `Action<>` type. Then assign this to `MulticastDelegate`.

In the example, I show both versions (through a method parameter and through a variable):

```
public static void CallTestDelegate()
{
    TestDelegate((d, s) => d.Height = Single.Parse(s));
}

public static void TestDelegate(Action<RectangleF, string> action)
{
    Dictionary<String, MulticastDelegate> dict = new Dictionary<string, MulticastDelegate>();
    dict.Add("a1", action);
    Action<RectangleF, string> action2 = (d, s) => d.Width = Single.Parse(s);
    dict.Add("a2", action2);

    var a1 = (Action<RectangleF, string>)dict["a1"];
    a1(new RectangleF(), "15");
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm getting the following error when I try to populate the actions: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.MulticastDelegate' because it is not a delegate type. I'm also getting an error when I perform a check on the actions: actions.TryGetValue(prop, out action)

Comment: I added an example. I also tested, if an anonymous delegate could, unlike lambdas, be passed directly to the `Add()` method. But here again the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make `Drawing<T>` derive from a non-generic interface `IDrawing` that has `Height` and `Width` properties, then change your actions to be of type `Action<IDrawing,String>`.

Another option (less type-safe) is to make your actions of type `Action<dynamic,String>`.

Comment: Option 1 would require too much work (if it can be done at all), I used a simplified example to show what my goal is. Can't use option 2 because the code has to be compatible with 3.5

Comment: @Manuel: Fair enough, though it does help to have the context of the question when answering the question. I've edited the tags appropriately as far as the .NET 3.5 requirement goes.

Answer (score 0):

T is just a placeholder, make an abstract class or interface representing objects that you want